# Как подписаться на изменение переменной?

Tags: javascript, angular2, rxjs

Помогите пожалуйста подписаться на изменение переменной. Я сделал простейший спиннер загрузки. Переменная, которая отвечает за его  видимость хранится в сервисе:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Response, Headers, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class GlobalVarsService {
    private isVisibleSpinner: boolean = false;

  getSpinnerState(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isVisibleSpinner;
  }; 

  setSpinnerState(state): void {
    console.log('setSpinnerState', state);
    this.isVisibleSpinner = state;
  };    
}
```

В шаблоне компонента я по условию выводу разметку спиннера:

```
<div class="nav">
  <a [routerLink]="['/select']">select</a>
  <a [routerLink]="['/output']">output</a>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>

<div class="spinner-backdrop" *ngIf="isVisibleSpinner"></div>
<div class="spinner-area" *ngIf="isVisibleSpinner">
    <span class="spinner">loading...</span>
</div>
```

В компоненте я пытаюсь подписаться на изменения, которые происходят в сервисе с переменной isVisibleSpinner:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { GlobalVarsService } from './services/global-vars.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    private isVisibleSpinner: boolean;

  constructor(private globalVarsService: GlobalVarsService) {  
        this.globalVarsService.getSpinnerState().subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
          this.isVisibleSpinner = data;
        });     
  }
}
```

Но консоль выводит следующее сообщение об ошибке:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'Observable'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Рассмотрим эту часть кода:

```
private isVisibleSpinner: boolean = false;

getSpinnerState(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.isVisibleSpinner;
};
```

Функция `getSpinnerState` возвращает переменную типа `boolean`, а должна возвращать `Observable<boolean>`. Что-то здесь не так. Я бы изменил тип переменной `isVisibleSpinner` на [`BehaviorSubject<boolean>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40231605/5812238):

```
private isVisibleSpinner = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

Соответственно метод `setSpinnerState` нужно переписать, используя `BehaviorSubject.next()`:

```
setSpinnerState(state): void {
  console.log('setSpinnerState', state);
  this.isVisibleSpinner.next(state);
};
```

---

Далее, в классе компонента я бы оставил только инжектирование сервиса:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(public globalVarsService: GlobalVarsService) {}
}
```

И переписал бы шаблон используя [`AsyncPipe`](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

```
... *ngIf="globalVarsService.getSpinnerState() | async" ...
```

Comment: это нормальная практика, только `constructor(private globalVarsService: GlobalVarsService) {}` изменить модификтор доступа на `public`, тк у нас все-таки `ts`

Comment: @Artsiom, отлично, спасибо, изменил.